# Flag and Rules module that an entered user automatically

Tags: drupal-7, flags, drupal-rules

I have a question, please tell me how can I set by "Flag" and "Rules" module that an entered user automatically, could adds the other users.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**# Thank you! [Shabana Blackborder](https://drupal.org/node/2043051)**

Basically, if you mean you would like to flag other users like in a 'friendship' type flag, when a new user is created, all you need to do is:

1. Create a flag which flags users, called 'flag users'
2. Create a rule where the event could be 'After saving a new user account'
   a. Create an action to that rule where 'flag user' is the action
   a. Then, you select the 'flag users' flag which you created earlier
   b. The user to flag: you can use the data selector to select whom you would like to flag or alternatively, use the direct input to specifically add a userid.
   c. User on whose behalf to flag: site:current-user or whatever you choose
   d. Click save.

That's all you need. So now, every time a new user is saved, the rule will automatically fire to flag the users of your preference.